# Symfony: Unable to load Twig Extension runtime

Tags: symfony, twig

I was following [this guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) to add a custom Twig extension to Symfony 4 project.

My `App\Twig\AppExtension` is as follow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('getController', [AppRuntime::class, 'getController'])
        ];
    }
}
```

And My `App\Twig\AppRuntime`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class AppRuntime
{
    private $request;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

    public function getController()
    {
        return $this->request->get('_controller');
    }
}
```

But If I try to use `getController()` function in a template, I'm getting this exception:
**Unable to load the "App\Twig\AppRuntime" runtime.**

The following line from Twig template produces this error:

```
echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->env->getRuntime('App\Twig\AppRuntime')->getController(), "html", null, true);
```

`php bin/console debug:container` shows `App\Twig\AppRuntime` as a correct service. I've also tried setting `App\Twig\AppRuntime` as a public service, but without luck.

What can be the problem here?

Comment: What is your version of Twig?  Support for what you are doing was added in Twig 1.26.

Comment: Have you tagged the `App\Twig\AppRuntime`  service with `twig.runtime`?

Comment: Yes It was `twig.runtime` tag. It is not documented anywhere...

Comment: In fact it is documented in the guide you linked but with very unnoticeable printing at the very end of the instruction. I had exactly the same problem when was doing my Twig extension first time but after some time I noticed it finally :)

Comment: you were missing `implements RuntimeExtensionInterface`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you forgot to tag your twig extension service.

Here you got explanation how to do it in the first example:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html

Answer (score 1):

To put the comments into an answer, there are two solutions to this error.

### Solution 1

1. [Implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843734/symfony-unable-to-load-twig-extension-runtime#comment96651250_50843734) `RuntimeExtensionInterface`

```
class AppRuntime implements RuntimeExtensionInterface
```

2. Enable autoconfigure for the runtime service

```yaml
App\Twig\AppRuntime:
    autoconfigure: true
```

### Solution 2

Add `twig.runtime` [tag to the runtime service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50843734/symfony-unable-to-load-twig-extension-runtime#comment88692917_50843734)

```yaml
App\Twig\AppRuntime:
    tags:
        - { name: twig.runtime }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem, my case was different, let me leave it here in case it helps anyone.

I was getting: `Unable to load the "MyCustomFunctions" runtime in "main" at line 1`

The way I am loading my functions is not inside an extension, but one by one, like so:

`$twig->addFunction(new TwigFunction('print',  'MyCustomFunctions::print'));`

This was my function definition as a method of class **`MyCustomFunctions`**:

```php
// just as an easy to test example
public function print($var = '') {
    return print_r($var, true);;
}
```

**SOLUTION** The problem was that the way I was loading the function was not consistent with the function declaration. I had forgotten to make the function declaration **`public static function`**, with that **`static`** in there. Now it matches the **`::`** callable used when loading the function.

Obvious, once you see it, but terribly not-obvious from the error message... it took me a long time to figure this one out.